# How to delete a control like splitcontainer from the form designer?

Tags: winforms

There are some UI elements like the SplitContainer which I can't delete in the form designer because I can't select it. If I select it from the properties window and hit delete, nothing happens. This should be a simple thing to do. I don't want to delete the control in the designer file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several options, there might be more:

- Press Ctrl+F6 to change the focus, press Delete
- Right-click, Select, press Delete
- Reset the Dock property, lasso-select, press Delete
- Use View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline, right-click + Delete.

Comment: Only the last option worked. In VS 2013 the Document Outline is under the view menu, outside Other Windows. I couldn't select or get the splitcontrol to get focus by the other methods.